# How to access multiple values of 3D numpy array using array of 3D indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I happen to have a 3D array (referred to as array A) with shape (360,360,360) which I would like to access using another array (referred to as array B) with shape (259200,3). Array B is composed of 259200 3-D arrays that represent indices of array A.

Is there a way for me to quickly generate a numpy array that contains the selection of 3D array A values that are associated with the indices in array B? I'm trying to avoid having to write an intensive for loop like this:

```
SubArray = []
for i in range(0,len(ArrayB)):
    Val = ArrayA[ArrayB[i][0],ArrayB[i][1],ArrayB[i][2]]
    SubArray.append(Val)
```

Comment: Is it not just ```A[B]```? Although this array is huge so my memory runs outs.

Comment: you can do `a[tuple(np.hsplit(b,np.size(b,1)))]` if you want to preserve the dimension of the index array, or `a[b[:,0],b[:,1],b[:,2]]` if you want a flattened array.

Comment: @Kevin I'm getting a problem where I don't think the value is being properly called. For example, if I call for ArrayA[B[0]], I end up getting an array of shape (3,360,360) returned, I think obchardon is right about including the tuple, but as you also mentioned, a memory issue still stands

Answer (score 0):

I have almost the same question but didn't have solution.

If I understand correctly, for example you have 1D numpy array

**Input:**

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=20)
```

**Output:**

```
array([5, 0, 3, 3, 7, 9, 3, 5, 2, 4, 7, 6, 8, 8, 1, 6, 7, 7, 8, 1])
```

**Input:**

```
arr[ np.array([0, 5, 10]) ]
```

**Output:**

```
array([5, 9, 7])
```

But I have problems with accessing to **3D numpy array**. So, I 'd like to set specified indexes for 3D array and get values.

For example, I have 3D array **data** with shape (512, 221, 35) and I have 2D array **table** with columns: ir, iphi, itheta, which are integer indexes for **data**.

For example:

| table |   ir |  iphi |  itheta 
| ------|------|-------|-------- 
| row0  |   0  |     0 |       0 
| row1  |   1  |    80 |      15 
| row2  |  50  |   151 |      18 
...

So I tried to get access by the same way
`data[ [[0, 0, 0], [1, 80, 15]]]`, i.e.
data[ array_of_3D_indices] but I had the **incorrect result** as an array with `shape (3, 35)` but actually I **expected 1D array** with shape (2,), where every triplet ( 3 indeces from 3d array) corresponds to 1 number from data.

**SOLUTION.**
I tried to get it by `data[ [ir1, iphi1, itheata1], [ir2, iphi2, itheata2]]` and get wrong result,
but when tried `data[ [ir1, ir2], [iphi1, iphi2], [itheta1, itheta2]]` got correct answer!
You should join the same dimensions in one array of indexes and get 3 arrays of indices.

for example:
`data[ [0,1,50], [0,80,151], [0,15,18]]` will have `shape (3,)`
And this is without for loop

**P.S.** better to write:
`data[ tuple( table )]`, whete table is 2D array of indices